# MongoDB error when inserting values with contain `.`

Tags: python, mongodb

```py
{'question1.': 'no', 'question2.': 'no.'}
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=InvalidDocument("key 'question1.' must not contain '.'")>
```

```py
        print(answers)
        self.client.applicants.insert_one(
            {
                "name": args,
                "userId": ctx.author.id,
                "guildId": ctx.guild.id,
                "questions": answers,
                "messageId": application_message.id,
            }
        )
```

Hey. I'm trying to insert this into my MongoDB database. However, i get the error above which says the question cannot contain `.`. How can I fix this without having to remove the punctuation from the question? As it would be ideal to have this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

It was possible in MongoDB version <= 3.6 where there was an option to bypass the validation completely using the `check_keys=False` option. But this option is deprecated ever since.

Although MongoDB has `bypass_document_validation=True` in newer versions, it won't bypass the `.` character for obvious reasons.

There is an open issue regarding this on JIRA [(SERVER-30575)](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30575) and it is still open. Also, the `PyMongo` specific issue related to this was raised once [PYTHON-1522](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-1522).

So until the [SERVER-30575](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30575) issue fixed, you have no other choice.

I would suggest you rearrange your schema design to embed the key name as a value to a different key.

Something like this:

```py
question = [
    {
        "question": "question1.",
        "answer": "no.",
    },
    {
        "question": "question2.",
        "answer": "yes.",
    },
]
```